# Why are all the Resistance members female?

Tags: casting, allo-allo

In the British World War II sit-com *'Allo 'Allo!*, it appears that all members of the French Resistance (even the Communist Resistance) are attractive young women. Obviously it's a comedy so there's some sort of joke going on there. Have the creators of the show ever spoken about or given a reason for this choice?

Comment: Guess who you forgot. Psst! _*lifts wig*_ It is I, Leclerc!

Answer (score 11):

One reason is the running gag that all the attractive young women are in love with René, but the reason the plot has that to play with is more visceral…

In the middle of World War II in France, there were no able-bodied men between 18 & 35 who weren't off fighting, captured or killed. There was a war on, don't you know?

Comment: OP actually forgot about Leclerc, but that further proves your point about able-bodied men between 18 and 35.